# why regex, when using global search and {0,} quantifier, match the end of the string?

Tags: javascript, strings, regular-expressions, string-matching

I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701862/js-regex-quantifiers-and-global-flag-outputs-empty-string-as-the-last-element-in) about js, regex, quantifiers and global search. I've understood finally how this works, but, let's take a concrete example and then I`ll write my question.

Based on the same example

```
var str = 'ddd';
var r = /d*/g;
console.log(str.match(r))
```

it outputs this array: `["ddd", ""]`

I understand that the first item in the array is because it matches the letter `d` and the last item (that empty string) is because it matches the end of the string, which is nothing, so * makes sense because it matches 0 or more occurrences...

So, my questions are:

- Why this is happening?
- Why it just have to query the end of the string to finally obtain a
  true matching?

In my opinion, the end of the string(ddd) should not be queried; because it's not like my string is containing an empty space at the end 'ddd '. If my string was empty, it was logical to match, but not in this case. My logic here is this:

for every character in the string, do this search/regex (d*) ...so why does it just continue with the end of the string? It should stop on the last charachter of my string, which in this case is `d`...

Answer (score 4):

`match` is just a wrapper for `exec`, per [ES5 15.5.4.10, step 8(f)(i)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10):

> Let *result* be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of exec with rx as the this value and argument list containing S.

For a global regex, `match` continuously calls `exec` until `exec` retruns a `null` value.

When we [look at `exec`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2), we see that each call to `exec` with a global regex increases the regex object's `lastIndex` after the match is made:

> 10. Let e be r's endIndex value.
> 11. If global is true,
>
>     - Call the [[Put]] internal method of R with arguments "lastIndex", e, and true.

However (**here's the real mechanical answer**), `lastMatch` is only reset by `exec` when it is *strictly greater* than the length of the string:

> 5. Let i be the value of ToInteger(lastIndex).
>
> ...
>
> 9. If i < 0 or i > length, then
>
>    - Call the [[Put]] internal method of R with arguments "lastIndex", 0, and true.
>    - Return null.

(Note `i > length`, not `i >= length`.)

Therefore, there will be a final attempt to match the substring whose left bound is `lastIndex` and whose right bound is the end of the string. Since the final match is done when those positions are identical, a last match attempt is always done on the empty string.

As it happens, `d*` matches the empty string (since `*` matches zero and up), so that match is included in the `match` results.

I cannot offer a surefire explanation why the matching does not stop when `lastIndex` equal string length. My guess is that this final empty-string check is necessary to match zero-length terminal regexes like `/$/` which would never match if considered against a non-zero-length substring.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches the `''` empty string with `d*`, because the `*` quantifier means zero or many times and that's zero `d` here.

And it's matched because when you use the `g` modifier it will not stop in the first match and continue matching, that's why you will get the second match.

This is **[a DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gZ9hD7/1)** without the `g` modifier and it doesn't match the `''`.

So if you don't want it to match the second one you can just remove the `g` modifier or better use one of the following regexes:

```
var r = /(^d*$)/g;
//Or the following one
var r = /(d+)/g;
```

You will force it to get only strings that exactly contains the letter `d`.

You can see **[the DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gZ9hD7/2)** here.

Comment: I know that I can avoid this 'problem', but for now, I just want to know, exactly how you said, why 'the g modifier it will not stop in the first match and continue matching' ? It just not make any sense because, as I said, in my string, after the last character (d) there is no other character, not event and empty space...

Comment: @GigiIonel: that is just the meaning of the "g" (=global) modifier - find all matching strings, not just the first one.

Comment: It's simply that the `g` modifier is used to perform a **global match** (*find all matches rather than stopping after the first match*)